# Replace matching files with local copies VS2015 publish

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2005, publishing

I remember that in Visual Studio 2010 there was "Replace matching files with local copies" checkbox
[image]

Where this checkbox/radiobutton in Visual Studio 2015 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS2015 it's not possible to set this option in the Publish Window.

But we can do it in another way. Right Click on Project->Properties->Package/Publish Web->Items to deploy

According to MSDN you we have these [options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942158(v=vs.110).aspx)

> **Only files needed to run this application.** This is the default value. Visual Studio tries to determine which files are required for
> the application to run successfully. For example, this includes
> assemblies in the bin folder, files generated during the build, and
> files marked as Content. To see if a file is marked as Content, select
> the file in Solution Explorer, and check the file's Build Action
> property in the Properties window. You can change the Build Action
> value to Content to cause the file to be deployed, or change it to
> something else, such as None, to prevent the file from being deployed.
> Some file types that are automatically set to Content include .master,
> .svc, .ashx, .asax, .skin, .browser, .config, .and sitemap. A file
> must be included in the project in order to have a Build Action
> property.
>
> **All files in this project.** Visual Studio deploys all files that are included in the project, regardless of their Build Action property
> values.
>
> **All files in the project folder.** Visual Studio deploys all files that are in the project folder and subfolders, regardless of whether
> they are included in the project or their Build Action property
> values.

**UPDATE**

I figured out another method how to update all files during publishing. I faced issue when some of my files were not updated properly (config,ascx and etc.), in my inetpub folder I had old version of files. So first I published site in another new folder and then replace files in inetpub folder with files from new folder.